# code for a recursive factorial funct, take user input put them in np array and print the factorial of them

Tags: python, numpy, recursion, factorial

**taking *inputs from user* and put them in a *numpy array***

```py
import numpy as np
array=[]
a=int(input('enter the array size'))
for i in range(a):
    i=int(input("value in["+ str(i) +"]"))
    array.append(i)

b = np.array(array)
print(b)
```

**here we are defining the *factorial function***

```py
def recur_factorial(c):  
    if c == 1:  
       return c  
    else:  
       return c*recur_factorial(c-1)
```

**printing the *factorial* of the elements of *array b***

```py
for item in b:
    if b[i] < 0:  
        print("Sorry, factorial does not exist for negative numbers")  
    elif b[i] == 0:  
        print("The factorial of 0 is 1")  
    else:  
        print("The factorial of", b[i], "is", recur_factorial(b[i]))
```

Comment: And your questions is...?

Comment: Why b[i] instead of item?